# What does 「いねえのかよ」mean?

Tags: meaning, reading-comprehension

It comes from the full sentence

[image]

The portion before the comma I translated as "I noticed that/a guy", as the character just woke up in a dark room and is hearing voices around him in the dim light. The portion after the comma I am confused about. Does it mean anything literally? I think it's basically a string of particles with a "questioning" {{JP:ねえ}}, an "inquisitive/forceful" {{JP:のか}}, and a determined {{JP:よ}}. With that I guess that it gives the reader the feeling that the character is uncertain whether to be happy or afraid that he/she has noticed this other person.

Comment: What were you reading, by the way?

Comment: @AeonAkechi I was reading Grimgar of Fantasy and Ash :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

～かよ tends to be a rough way of expressing surprise, like when you look at your watch and see it's already 11:30 PM. もうこんな時間かよ？！

Additionally, わかるやつ here does not - and cannot - mean 'I noticed that guy'. The word わかる here is an entire relative clause modifying やつ, so わかるやつ is 'a person/people who understand(s)/know(s)'.

Your understanding of ～ねえ here is wrong as well. It's not an elongated ね; rather it's a slangy pronunciation of ～ない. いねえ is a rough, slangy いない.

Accordingly the sentence わかるやつ、いねえのかよ means something like 'Come on, ain't there anybody who understands/knows?!'

By the way, it's a much better idea to show us the surrounding sentences rather than simply explaining the context yourself.

PS: Now that I know what you were reading and have been able to look up the context myself, it looks like the meaning was 'Ain't there anybody who knows where we are?!'